# Handle zero values in react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pie-chart, react-chartjs

i'm using react-chartjs-2 for customizing three donut pie charts. This library is amazing with many functionalities but i'm having a problem here. I dont know how to handle zero values. When all my values are zero not pie chart is drawn which is correct. Any ideas of how to handle zero values?? This is my code for drawing a doughnut pie chart:

```
const renderPortfolioSectorPie = (sectors, intl) => {
  if (sectors.length > 0) {
    const sectorsName = sectors
      .map(sector => sector.name);
    const sectorsValue = sectors
      .map(sector => sector.subtotal);
    const sectorsPercentage = sectors
      .map(sector => sector.percentage);
    const customeSectorsPercentage = sectorsPercentage.map(h =>
      `(${h})`
    );
    let sectorsCounter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < sectorsName.length; i += 1) {
      if (sectorsName[i] !== sectorsName[i + 1]) {
        sectorsCounter += 1;
      }
    }
    const sectorsData = {
      datasets: [{
        data: sectorsValue,
        backgroundColor: [
          '#129CFF',
          '#0c6db3',
          '#4682B4',
          '#00FFFF',
          '#0099FF',
          '#3E3BF5',
          '#3366CC',
          '#3399FF',
          '#6600FF',
          '#3366CC',
          '#0099CC',
          '#336699',
          '#3333FF',
          '#2178BA',
          '#1F7AB8',
          '#1C7DB5'
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
          '#129cff',
          '#0c6db3',
          '#4682B4',
          '#00FFFF',
          '#0099FF',
          '#3E3BF5',
          '#3366CC',
          '#3399FF',
          '#3366CC',
          '#0099CC',
          '#336699',
          '#3333FF',
          '#2178BA',
          '#1F7AB8',
          '#1C7DB5'
        ],
        titles: sectorsName,
        labels: sectorsValue,
        afterLabels: customeSectorsPercentage,
      }]
    };

    return (
      <Doughnut
        data={sectorsData}
        width={250}
        height={250}
        redraw
        options={{
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          responsive: true,
          cutoutPercentage: 80,
          animation: {
            animateRotate: false,
            animateScale: false
          },
          elements: {
            center: {
              textNumber: `${sectorsCounter}`,
              text: intl.formatMessage({ id: 'pie.sectors' }),
              fontColor: '#4a4a4a',
              fontFamily: "'EurobankSans'",
              fontStyle: 'normal',
              minFontSize: 25,
              maxFontSize: 25,
            }
          },
          /*eslint-disable */
          tooltips: {
            custom: (tooltip) => {
              tooltip.titleFontFamily = 'Helvetica';
              tooltip.titleFontColor = 'rgb(0,255,255)';
            },
            /* eslint-enable */
            callbacks: {
              title: (tooltipItem, data) => {
                const titles = data.datasets[tooltipItem[0]
                  .datasetIndex].titles[tooltipItem[0].index];
                return (
                  titles
                );
              },
              label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
                const labels = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex]
                  .labels[tooltipItem.index];
                return (
                  labels
                );
              },
              afterLabel: (tooltipItem, data) => {
                const afterLabels = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex]
                  .afterLabels[tooltipItem.index];
                return (
                  afterLabels
                );
              },
            },
          },
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: `When all my values are zero not pie chart is drawn which is correct.` - so what **is** the problem?

Comment: What would you like the output to be?  A pie chart showing equal area for all sectors?

Comment: I think this would be the best solution

Comment: @JaromandaX the problem is that i dont want to show nothing when values are zero. I want to show a small part showing that value is zero

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, but I could not find a way to do it. So, that is what I found as a workaround:

After getting the data, you update your options:

```
this.setState({
    doughnutOptions: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function () {
                    let value = response.data.total;
                    let label = response.data.name;

                    return value === 0 ? label : label + ': ' + value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My Doughnut looks like that:

```
<Doughnut data={this.state.myData} min-width={200} width={400}
          height={400} options={this.state.doughnutOptions}/>
```

And initially, the doughnutOpitions are just one empty object defined in the state:

```
doughnutOptions: {}
```

That is how it will look when no data:

[image]

If you have found a better way of showing no data, please share. If not, I hope that workaround would be good enough for you!